# I installed a font and now it is used as the default font in web pages

Tags: 11.04, fonts

I installed a font called `SegoeWP.ttf` and now in every browser its the font for each page unless the page has a pre EMBEDDED font. It doesn't matter if the page has a stated font like:

```
font:verdana;
```

or something like that, it is using SegoeWP and now Ubuntu has this ridiculous way of storing fonts and now I can't find it to uninstall it.

Comment: This question is abandoned. If you feel this is in error, please flag explaining why and the moderators will reopen it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall fonts using `Synaptic Package Manager`. Type the offending font's name in the Quick filter field, find it on the list, right-click it and select Mark for removal, and click the Apply button.

As to why this problem is happening in the first place, I'm afraid I have no idea...