# Installed font on Ubuntu, now Ubuntu Chrome, Firefox, all browsers etc... use that font?

Tags: 11.04, unity, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I installed a font and now Ubuntu is using it as the default font in web pages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55448/i-installed-a-font-and-now-ubuntu-is-using-it-as-the-default-font-in-web-pages)

I installed a font called "SegoeWP" it's made by Microsoft and used in their WP7 devices. However, all webpages in every browser use this font even though their specified fonts in their options menu do not say SegoeWP or anything similar. I also went to change the font in system wide selection and it isn't displayed there either.

How do I stop this? :(

[image]

[image]

[FIX]

If you have a similar problem with a font you installed, follow these instructions:
~ Install font manager from Software Center
~ Open and go to "User" on the left
~ Disable all offending fonts 
~ Open a terminal and run "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: Put the Fix as an answer please and accept it, don't put the fix in the question.

Comment: Is `sudo apt-get update` the correct command (or even necessary)?

Comment: Uri: I don't know how, sorry. Roland: I ran the command and watched Chrome update itself.

Comment: @Earl you already asked essentially the same question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55448/i-installed-a-font-and-now-ubuntu-is-using-it-as-the-default-font-in-web-pages) but didn't mention if you tried my answer.

Comment: Turns out this question [has already been asked](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55448/i-installed-a-font-and-now-ubuntu-is-using-it-as-the-default-font-in-web-pages). It'd be very cool if you could take the time to add your answer to this question instead.